# How to encode NSString correctly for SQLite all the while preserving Scandinavian letters

Tags: objective-c, ios, string, sqlite, nsstring

I'm currently working on an IOS app that will have fulltext search. The search is performed by performing a select statement on a sqlite database, but the problem is that many of the values in the database contain Scandinavian letters (Æ, Ö, Á etc) and I'm having trouble converting the statement without getting hex values for the letters.

Here is what I'm currently doing:

```
 const char *sql = [[NSString stringWithFormat:
                     @"SELECT %@\
                     FROM Customer c\
                     JOIN Customer_Metadata cm ON c.CustomerId = cm.CustomerId\
                     WHERE cm.Name LIKE '%%%@%%'\
                     ORDER BY cm.Name", kCustomerSelect, searchString] UTF8String];
```

Now kCustomerSelect is a constant containing the columns I want to select, and searchString contains the user input.

This works like a charm for normal Latin letters, but if I for instance pass along Ö, as a searchString, I get st\xc3\xb6. I am aware that simply logging out a UTF8 encoded string will not give correct representation of the string, but the problem is that my select statement isn't giving me any results.

I'm calling sqlite3_open() before executing the query and from the SQLite documentation *"The default encoding for the database will be UTF-8 if sqlite3_open() or sqlite3_open_v2() is called and UTF-16 in the native byte order if sqlite3_open16() is used."*.

I've tried using different encodings by replacing `UTF8String` with `cStringUsingEncoding:` and trying out different encodings. None of them have worked (not that I was expecting them, but at least wanted to try).

Any and all help, or tips, would be appreciated.

**Edit**
I've now tried using SQLite Database Browser to run the same select statement on the database and am not getting any results. 
This is leading me to believe that this might have something to do with me using FTS3 to create my Customer_Metadata table.

MrDresden

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using FTS3, the default tokenizer isn't going to do what you want.

> > > Unless a specific tokenizer is specified as part of the CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE statement used to create the FTS table, the default tokenizer, "simple", is used. The simple tokenizer extracts tokens from a document or basic FTS full-text query according to the following rules:
> > >
> > > A term is a contiguous sequence of eligible characters, where eligible characters are all alphanumeric characters and all characters with Unicode codepoint values greater than or equal to 128. All other characters are discarded when splitting a document into terms. Their only contribution is to separate adjacent terms.

-- http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#tokenizer

You'll need to use a custom tokenizer, or see if the icu or unicode61 tokenizers will work for you. Info about those are in the above linked doc.

Comment: Sadly, after trying both ICU and Unicode61, I still don't get results. I may need to create a custom tokenizer as you say.

Answer (score 0):

Write your query like this:

```
const char *sql = [[NSString stringWithFormat:
                 @"SELECT %@\
                 FROM Customer c\
                 JOIN Customer_Metadata cm ON c.CustomerId = cm.CustomerId\
                 WHERE cm.Name LIKE ?\
                 ORDER BY cm.Name", kCustomerSelect] UTF8String];
```

After you prepare the statement, bind the searchString:

```
sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%%%@%%", searchString] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
```

As long as the database is UTF-8, then you can enter text in Greek, Russian, Japanese, and of course using various Scandinavian characters.

Edit: I just saw your edit. If the data wasn't created properly, that would certainly be an issue.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried your suggestion but am still not getting results for "special" letters. I'm really starting to think I need to find a special tokanizer for my FTS3 tables.

Comment: Just a side note (ignoring the immediate issue for the moment) - the reason you should use `sqlite_bind_xxx` over string formats is because `sqlite_bind_xxx` properly handles cases like the string value containing quotes. Is solves SQL-injection attacks as well. Good luck with the FTS issue.